# Angular with universal renders the page twice

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am using angular with universal, but the page is loaded twice, the first one without the api data and the second one already brings them loaded

Does someone know how to solve this problem ?

This is the way I make requests to my API

```
getPagination(event, red=false) {
        if(red){
            this.router.navigate(['/eventos/'+event]);
        }else{
            this.events = new Array();
            this.loading = true;
            this.p=event;
            //if (this.events.length < this.totalEvents) {
                const filter = "ordering=startDate&items=" + this.pageSize + "&page=" + event;
                let urlfilter = '';

                for (let filter in this.filters) {
                    if(this.filters[filter] != ''){
                        urlfilter += '&'+filter+'='+this.filters[filter];
                    }
                }
                this.api.getEvents(filter + urlfilter).subscribe(res =>{
                    this.totalEvents = res['count'];
                    this.events = res['results'];
                    this.loading = false;
                }, err=>{
                    this.loading = false;
                })
            //}
        }
    }
```

This is my method in the API service

```
 getEvents(where?: string): Observable<any> {
    where = (where) ? '?' + where : '';
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + `events/${where}`)
    .pipe(map(res =>  res), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Comment: Use the TransferState api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version you are using there are different ways to use the TransferState API.  Once you get to Angular 7, it gets pretty easy.

In AppModule import BrowserModule like this:

```
HttpClientModule,
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'your-app-id' }),
BrowserTransferStateModule,
```

If I recall correctly I remember the order might be important with HttpClientModule.  Then, when you make http calls with HttpClient, api calls from server will be cached and not remade on browser.